# How can a user start its own login shell?

Tags: shell, docker, login, passwd

I want the default command for a Docker image to start up a login shell for the container's user.¹

Something like:

```
…
USER someuser
CMD /bin/zsh --login
```

That above gets a login shell, but does not change the working directory to `someuser`'s home, nor does it honor `someuser`'s `/etc/passwd` entry. `sudo --user someuser --login` will achieve the desired result (correct shell, working directory as user's home), but that depends on `someuser` being properly provisioned in `/etc/sudoers` and leaves the parent `sudo` process hanging around. I don't want to rely on `sudo` at all, if I don't have to.

I have tried `/usr/bin/login -p -f someuser` as the command, but this doesn't seem to work (not sure what the error is).

One can try something like `CMD sh -c 'cd "${HOME}" ; SHELL="${SHELL}" exec -a "-${SHELL##*/}" "${SHELL}"'` ([derived from a discussion with a different, but related context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304447/106705)). This seems to work, but that depends on `SHELL` being set and the referenced shell inferring that it should start as a login shell when it's zeroth argument starts with a `-`. Is this idiomatic? I don't know if `SHELL` is always set or whether prefixing the user shell with `-` will always work. (Note that `CMD sh -c '… exec -l "${SHELL}"'` doesn't get it quite right, because the zeroth argument gets set to, e.g., `-/usr/bin/zsh`.)

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584311/106705) seems to suggest `agetty` can create the desired effect, but seems like a mismatch on how to get there. I also don't want to engage in my own [`grep`/`awk` shenanigans with `/etc/passwd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352316/106705) (although [`getent passwd "$( id -u )" | cut -d : -f 7`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352320/106705) seems to be the least obnoxious of these approaches).

Is there a way a user can start its own login shell as if the user were logging in without naming the shell or the home directory explicitly and without a password?

There has to be something more idiomatic than `exec python -c 'import os, pwd, re ; ent = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()) ; os.chdir(ent.pw_dir) ; os.execv(ent.pw_shell, (re.sub(r"^.*/", "-", ent.pw_shell),))'`.

---

¹ The image is meant to create a persistent, named container that houses a sandboxed, interactive environment for experimentation with a specific set of pre-installed applications. (This isn't some containerized web application. Think of running a highly customized suite of Linux-only math/science apps on a Windows host with minimal required configuration.) Power users may want to change the login shell for `someuser` inside the container via `chsh`, and that should be honored by the default command.

Comment: What does it mean "does not honor someuser's /etc/passwd entry" exactly? And how do you start and connect to the container? What are your exact `docker` commands?

Comment: “I don't want to engage in grep/awk shenanigans with /etc/passwd.” How else do you hope this to work? The “shenanigans with /etc/passwd” (more accurately, the library functions that `getent` is a shell wrapper around) are how `login` and friends work.

Comment: "How else do you hope this to work?" I'm assuming there is some standard tooling/idiomatic way to start a login shell for a user that invokes what is found in `/etc/passwd`. As you say, `login` already does this. What I'm asking about is whether it can do it without requiring the user to reenter a password if a user is starting its own login shell. `login` does some other stuff that is helpful (e.g., sets the home directory, changes the current working directory to home, etc.). I would like to invoke that machinery, whatever it is, but I don't know how to discover that.

Comment: @aviro, apologies for being unclear. Forget Docker for a minute. Let's just say you're running `weirdsh` (not your login shell) interactively as `someuser` and want to replace that process with a clean shell (listed in `someuser`'s entry in `/etc/passwd`) as if `someuser` had just logged in (complete with changing your working directory to your home as listed in `/etc/passwd`). What command do you type?

Comment: I have to admit it's a good point, and you would expect there would be an easy way to do that, but I don't think there is, as weird as it sounds. If I were you I would write some tool or a script (like the python script you showed, but it would be pretty easy to just write some short c code that would do the same), add it to the container and make it the default `CMD`.

Comment: @posita Have you tried using [su(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/su)? Its switch `-l` makes the shell a login shell.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, did you see the part about not requiring a password? `su -l "${USER}"` prompts for the user's password.

Comment: With regards to your question about the "minus", [POSIX standard for execvp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) states: _In some cases the filename passed is not the actual filename of the file; for example, many implementations of the login utility use a convention of prefixing a <hyphen-minus> ( '-' ) to the actual filename, which indicates to the command interpreter being invoked that it is a "login shell"._ But I don't see how else could you circumvent entering password without some setuid program or program running as root executing your shell.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, I'm confused how your comments pertain to my situation. I shouldn't need `setuid`. As stated in the title, the user is starting its own login shell. There's no escalation. The `python` "one-liner" above doesn't need `setuid`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if there is no command (other than `sudo`) for a user to start its own login shell without requiring a password and without being told explicitly what that shell is. According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352319/106705), a user's `SHELL` variable is *always* set to their login shell. In my testing, that's not strictly true:

```bsh
% # SHELL is set if you're coming from bash ...
% docker run --rm debian:latest bash -c 'set -eux ; echo "${0}" ; echo "${SHELL}"'
bash
/bin/bash
+ echo bash
+ echo /bin/bash
# ... but not from sh? (Yikes!)
% docker run --rm debian:latest sh -c 'set -eux ; echo "${0}" ; echo "${SHELL}"'
+ echo sh
sh: 1: SHELL: parameter not set
sh
% # And USER is only set for interactive shells, maybe?
% docker run --rm debian:latest bash -c 'set -eux ; echo "${USER}"'
bash: line 1: USER: unbound variable
```

So, unless I've missed something, it appears the following is (unfortunately) probably the most robust way for a user to start its own login shell without a password.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -ux

# USER isn't always set.
USER="${USER:-$( id -u )}"

# SHELL isn't always set. How fragile is that field number?
SHELL="${SHELL:-$( getent passwd "${USER}" | cut -d : -f 7 )}"

if [ -z "${SHELL}" ] ; then
  echo 1>&2 "${0}: can't set SHELL; giving up"
  exit 1
fi

# Dunno about HOME, but why relinquish our skepticism now?
HOME="${HOME:-$( getent passwd "${USER}" | cut -d : -f 6 )}"

if [ -z "${HOME}" ] ; then
  echo 1>&2 "${0}: can't set HOME; giving up"
  exit 1
fi

cd "${HOME}"

# This assumes that a shell knows it should be a login shell if its exec'ed argument
# begins with a "-".
SHELL="${SHELL}" exec -a "-${SHELL##*/}" "${SHELL}"
```

That's…*a lot*. I would have expected there to be a better way….